# How to understand "keeping in mind" in these sentences?

Tags: idiom-meaning

What does the keeping in mind in the following sentences mean? I find it hard to understand the whole sentence.

> A: According to the present needs, a change should be made in laws. For example, in the past, there were restrictions put the merchants to practice free trade keeping in mind the upliftment of small scale industry and public sector.
>
> B: Similarly, there can be changes in circumstances that require a change in laws. For example, in case of violence or attack, it becomes essential to put restriction over the common man keeping in mind the interests of the society.

Answer (score 1):

***[Keep something in mind,  also keep in mind something:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+in+min)*** :

> - to remember a piece of information when you are doing something or thinking about a matter.

In your second example, for instance, it refers to the fact that the interest of society will be "taken into due consideration"  when restrictions  over the common man will be implemented.

Comment: Can I speak either of the sentences in oral English?

Comment: @layten anything that can be written down can also be spoken.